# How to plot the derivative of a very complicated function

Tags: python, derivative

This question is related with the [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation). So as you can see, the equation is super long and I defined a lot of variables to simplify this long equation. I want to plot `(dU/dt)*(dP/dt)^-1` where `U` and `P` are all defined in the code. This equation has a lot of variables which makes it complicated to do this task. I have tried all the methods I could and I still cannot get a good result. Please help me, thank you so much.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym  

# These are the constant variables I defined 
kb = 1.381e-23
h = 6.626e-34
me = 9.109e-31
mh = 1.67e-27
pi = math.pi
rho1 = 10e-7
rho2 = 10e-5
rho3 = 10e-3


#the following variables will be used in the definition of P and U
t = np.linspace(5000, 25000, 1000)
k1 =(1/rho1)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)
k2 = 2.18e-18/kb 
k3 =(1/rho2)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)
k4 =(1/rho3)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)

x1 = ((-k1* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k1**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k1*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)
x2 = ((-k3* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k3**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k3*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)
x3 = ((-k4* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k4**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k4*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)

# I defined P and U here 
P = (rho3/mh)*(1+x3)*(kb*t)
U = 1.5*P + rho3*x3*2.18e-18/(mh)
```

Comment: It is too hard to read, could you please attach an expression?

Comment: Could you detail what exactly you have tried, what was the output and how that output was unexpected/unusable?

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1**:
Calculate the derivative analytically, e.g. with [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or by hand and plot it.

**Option #2**:
Use numerical gradient approximations, for example [np.gradient()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html). Here is an example for your problem:

```py
def saha(t):
    kb = 1.381e-23
    h = 6.626e-34
    me = 9.109e-31
    mh = 1.67e-27
    pi = math.pi
    rho1 = 10e-7
    rho2 = 10e-5
    rho3 = 10e-3
    k1 =(1/rho1)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)
    k2 = 2.18e-18/kb 
    k3 =(1/rho2)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)
    k4 =(1/rho3)*(mh*((2*3.1415926*me*kb)**(3/2)))/(h**3)

    x1 = ((-k1* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k1**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k1*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)
    x2 = ((-k3* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k3**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k3*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)
    x3 = ((-k4* (t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)+np.sqrt((k4**2)*(t**3)*np.exp(-k2*2/t)+4*k4*(t**(3/2))*np.exp(-k2/t)))/2)
    P = (rho3/mh)*(1+x3)*(kb*t)
    U = 1.5*p + rho3*x3*2.18e-18/(mh)
    return P, U

# compute U and P
t = np.linspace(5000, 25000, 1000)
p, u = saha(t)

# compute gradients of U and P w.r.t. T
u_grad = np.gradient(u)
p_grad = np.gradient(p)

# plot
plt.plot(t,u_grad * 1/(p_grad))
plt.ylabel("(dU/dt)*(dP/dt)^-1")
plt.xlabel("T")
plt.savefig("saha.png",dpi=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I tried the exact code you posted, but there is no graph showing up, Why is this happening, thank you so much for you answer though!!!!

Comment: `plt.savefig()` will save the figure. You can use `plt.show()` to simply display the plot.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the finite difference method to calculate approximations of dU/dt and dP/dt and plot your required derivative.

Comment: Elegant, matplotlib only do dots and lines, plotting an expression means to parse it to n dots.

Comment: @Weilory that is correct. But that is already what the TS is doing, so it wouldn't be too hard to do it. Option #2 below is already doing exactly that.